# Deployed Rails 3.2 App to Cloud Foundry, Connection Refused and Empty Logs

Tags: https, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cloud-foundry

I have deployed a Rails 3.2 application to a Micro Cloud Foundry running locally in a VM. The `vmc push` finishes successfully, and running `vmc logs` shows

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:54263
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:54263, CTRL+C to stop
```

There are no other errors or even warnings mentioned in the logs. When I connect to the application using `blah.myname.cloudfoundry.me` URL, I notice that the app redirects to HTTPS and then displays Connection Refused.

Just to be sure the problem is not with my Micro Cloud Foundry setup, I deployed a simple Sinatra Hello World app and it worked great.

What steps can I take to help debug this, because `vmc logs` is not giving any help? Are there other logs I can access from the Micro Cloud Foundry VM via SSH which may have clues to the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that thin is being bound to port 54263 on the VM, it may be worth SSHing to the vm and using curl to open 127.0.0.1:54263

It's also worth checking the Rails application logs too, you can do this using "vmc files" command and passing the path app/logs/production.log

Comment: I did as you suggested and used `curl 127.0.0.1:54263`, and the HTML for my page was returned. However, accessing `blah.myname.cloudfoundry.me` in my browser still fails to work. In the Rails application logs, I can see the successful rendering of home (from my curl test), but no other activity. It seems like the browser traffic to my app's subdomain isn't even reaching Rails.